# object in not callable in GUI temperature converter

Tags: python

I'm doing an assignment in Python for a converter between Celsius and Fahrenheit.
The GUI frame appears but the terminal says the FloatField object isn't callable. the error resides within the computeCelsius function within the line that says getNumber(). Trying to ind a solution please help.

```
from breezypythongui import EasyFrame

class TemperatureConverter(EasyFrame):
    """A termperature conversion program."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Sets up the window and widgets."""
        EasyFrame.__init__(self, width = 1000, title = "Temperature Converter")

        
        self.addLabel(text = "Celsius", row = 0, column = 0)
        self.addLabel(text = "Fahrenheit", row = 0, column = 1)

        self.CelsiusField = self.addFloatField(value = 0.0, row = 1, column = 0)
        self.FahrenheitField = self.addFloatField(value = 32.0, row = 1, column = 1)
        
        self.grp1 = self.addButton(text = ">>>>", row = 2, column = 0, command = self.computeFahrenheit)
        
        self.grp2 = self.addButton(text = "<<<<", row = 2, column = 1, command = self.computeCelsius)
    
    
    def computeFahrenheit(self):
        inputVal = self.CelsiusField().getNumber()
        farh = 9.0/5.0 * inputVal + 32
        self.getInputFahrenheit.setValue(farh)
      

    def computeCelsius(self):
        inputVal = self.FahrenheitField().getNumber()
        cels = (farh - 32) * 5.0/9.0
        self.getInputCelsius.setValue(cels)
        
def main():
    """Instantiate and pop up the window."""
    TemperatureConverter().mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: `inputVal = self.CelsiusField().getNumber()` should be `inputVal = self.CelsiusField.getNumber()`. Same deal with the corresponding line in the next method.

Comment: you should break that line containig getnumber into 3. first just take the self. then take the celsiusField. Then run the getnumber. then you can analyze between those calls, try to see where the error appears and then you are closer to the solution. this can never be said enough, but divide and conquer.